# Error extract file on https://files.000webhost.com/

Tags: php, zip, extract, unzip

I want to extract file on 000webhost website but got this error .Do anyone know what to do?
Thanks.
[visit below link for clear message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DoLs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have gone over your limit on disk space. Try deleting some files first and extract the file again

Comment: i think webhost error,my friend like that.